# Change location/file path of tests in Protractor

Tags: protractor, gherkin, end-to-end

I am using protractor to run End-to-end tests and I was wondering if it was possible to change the locations of where the tests it needs to perform are. I am hoping to be able to pass it in as a command line parameter.

For example this is the current set up:

[image]

Protractor currently looks the tests in the path `./tests` and then runs the features in the features folder.
I have done a lot of looking around and cannot find where it is defined that this is the path that it uses. I am wanting to be able to pass it a parameter, when run from the command line, along the lines of `--params.tests="C:\path\to\tests"`.

EDIT: I am using Mocha as my test framework

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have configured Cucumber as a custom framework in Protractor config file and triggering the tests by running the 'conf.js'

Current Setup might be:

```
specs: ['tests/features/*.features'],
cucumberOpts: {
    // This will point to your dependencies. Script files which contain  dependencies
    require: 'tests/steps/*.js',
},
```

Change it to CLI to accept these values at run-time

`protractor conf.js --specs tests/features/*.features --cucumberOpts.require tests/steps/*.js`

Comment: No sorry I am using Mocha, I will update my question but I feel what you have put will be some help. I don't have a `conf.js` file, my equivalent file is the `protractor_base.js`. Inside that file there is no `specs:` however, will I be able to add this to that file so that it can be used?